# Why do we get 'bags under our eyes'?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, human-eye

Why do these circles form around the eyes if somebody is tired? And why does fatigue express itself around the eyes this way? Can I get eye bags very quickly in another way?

[image]

[image]

http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2014/06/causes-dark-circles-eyes-sleeping-people-really-tired/

http://www.top10homeremedies.com/how-to/how-to-get-rid-of-dark-circles-fast.html

Comment: It's considered a requisite on biology.se that at least some reading/research is carried out and presented with your question. Otherwise it will be closed as *homework*. The [site tour](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help)  provide guidance on how to use this site. Please take a few minutes to read about the kind of questions which are on topic here

Comment: I edited your wording. I wasn't entirely sure what you meant with your last question "How can I get it really fast?", so I re-worded that sub question as best as I could. If you are unhappy with the edits, feel free to change or roll back.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to change the title from 'why do we get eye bags'

Comment: I know that dark circles and bags are two different things with different causes, the dark circles are mostly related to breathing problems while the bags are related to fluid retention, although these answers don't satisfy me which is why I'm still researching.

Comment: A possible answer for the first image may be that if you sleep badly you release more of the cortisol stress hormone, which breaks down your skin collagen across your entire body, which makes your skin thinner and reveals the blood behind the dark circles with a dark blue tint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Mayo Clinic website](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/bags-under-eyes/basics/causes/con-20034185):

> As you age, the tissue structures and muscles supporting your eyelids weaken. The skin may start to sag, and fat that is normally confined to the area around the eye (orbit) can move into the area below your eyes. Also, the space below your eyes can accumulate fluid, making the under-eye area appear puffy or swollen. Several factors can lead to this, including:
>
> - Fluid retention due to changes in weather (for example, hot, humid days)
> - hormone levels or eating salty foods
> - Not getting enough sleep
> - Allergies or dermatitis, especially if puffiness is accompanied by redness and itching
> - Heredity — under-eye bags can run in families

Of the list above, the most common reason is likely heredity.

Sources:

- Mayo Clinic, as linked above
- http://www.allaboutvision.com/cosmetic/puffy-eyes.htm

Comment: http://health.howstuffworks.com/skin-care/problems/beauty/what-causes-bags-under-eyes.htm Good answer +1

Comment: @CRags Thank you! I appreciate the feedback-- good or bad! I read that article as well, it was helpful.